# Calling a function in main window from child window declared in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This problem makes me crazy and I couldn't find any solution for hours. I believe you guys can help me with that.

I have controller in my `controller.js` file which has all info about my page. And I have a button in this page, it opens same page in a new popup window. I am trying to call a function in my main window once user click on a button on popup page.

My `controller.js`:

```
.controller('rackLayoutController', ['$scope', 'appService', 'rackLayoutService', 'siteService', '$location', '$log', '$sanitize', '$window', '$timeout',
function ($scope, appService, rackLayoutService, siteService, $location, $log, $window, $timeout) {

$( window ).ready(function() {
    function refreshPopout(){
        $(window).ready(function(){
            console.log("readyyyyy");
            setTimeout(function () {

                window.location.reload();

            }, 1000);

            });
        }
    });

    $scope.$on('updateRack', function () {
        console.log("BROAD 1");
        window.opener.refreshPopout();    

    })
```

When user clicks on button I am calling `broadcast updateRack` and it is printing my `log` which is fine, but the function is not working.

I am getting error :

`TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'refreshPopout'`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( window ).ready(function() {
    function refreshPopout(){
```

refreshPopout is not global when you call it.

try:

```
$( window ).ready(function() {
    window.refreshPopout = function(){
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Since it is the same page(but different windows) I thought I don't have to make it global. It works now.